# Mysql 5.7 ERROR 3143 (42000): Invalid JSON path expression. The error is around character position 3

Tags: mysql, json

iam using mysql 5.7.17 (latest version)

> this is my table samp1

```
mysql> select *from samp1;  

+-----+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| id  | jdoc                                                           |
+-----+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| 101 | {"k1": 12, "k2": 34}                                           |
| 111 | {"k1": 12, "k2": 34, "k3": {"L1": "value1", "L2": "value2"}}   |
| 112 | {"k1": 12, "k2": 34, "k3": {"L1": "value1", "L2": "value2"}}   |
| 125 | {"7": "123", "8": 10, "9": "hey", "10": ["dar", "sne", "swo"]} |
+-----+----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

> when i use below query it's executing properly

```
select id,jdoc -> "$.k3" as f from samp1  ;
```

> but when i use this query with single number key. it throwing error,why?

```
select id,jdoc -> "$.7" as f from samp1  ;

 ERROR 3143 (42000): Invalid JSON path expression. The error is around character position 3.
```

Comment: Have you tried `'$."7"'`? As per documentation, if a key is not valid in a path, you need to enclose it by double quotes.

Comment: @Shadow thanks man...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This should work:

```
select id,jdoc -> '$."7"' as f from samp1
```

Comment: this also works for keys that have a dash `-` in them such as v4 uuids.

Answer (score 0):

Was having the same Error on a JSON path which contained a hyphen `JSON_EXTRACT(path, '$.foo-bar')`
The solution proposed worked perfectly:

`JSON_EXTRACT(path, '$."foo-bar"')`