# Error Code: 3143. Invalid JSON path expression. The error is around character position 3

Tags: mysql, mysql-json

I'm getting the hang of SQL but am struggling with JSON data handling. I just can't get it to work. I'm getting the subject error when trying to run a very basic query, so I'm missing something fundamental.

I've read through many tutorials and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41958183/mysql-5-7-error-3143-42000-invalid-json-path-expression-the-error-is-around) but I think I need an example using the data I'm working with.

Error

```
Error Code: 3143. Invalid JSON path expression. The error is around character position 3.
```

Example JSON Data

```
{"1": {"name": "Part Source", "type": "Drop-Down List", "value": "Manufactured"}, "28": {"name": "Status", "type": "Drop-Down List", "value": "Current"}}
{"1": {"name": "Part Source", "type": "Drop-Down List", "value": "Manufactured"}, "28": {"name": "Status", "type": "Drop-Down List", "value": "Current"}}
{"1": {"name": "Part Source", "type": "Drop-Down List", "value": "Manufactured"}, "28": {"name": "Status", "type": "Drop-Down List", "value": "Current"}}
```

The data resides in a table named `part` in a column named `customFields`.

I've tried many things but to start simple, below is my attempt to extract the name from the first nested key pair. This yields the above error.

```
SELECT customFields->>'$.1.name'

FROM part;
```

I also tried with this the positional [0] and [1] after `$.1.name` with the same result.

Comment: That's not JSON data, that's a *series* of JSON documents. A JSON field should contain *one* JSON document and one only. If these were in an array like `[ { ... }, { ... }, ... ]` it'd be fine.

Comment: Tip: Use `jsonb` which rejects invalid JSON when inserting.

Comment: The JSON data is not the problem. The error says that the problem is the JSON _path_ in your extract expression: `'$.1.name'` needs to be `'$."1".name'` because path elements that start with digits need to be double-quoted.