# Nested JSON using MySQL

Tags: mysql, nested-json

I am trying to use MySQL to query a column 'XYZ' and the value of column 'XYZ' is like a nested JSON as shown below

```
{
 "sng_ecommerce_purchase_revenue": {"7d": 18},
 "unique_sng_content_view": {"7d": 25},
 "Unique_login_send_otp": {"7d": 22.0},
 "Unique_conversation_clicked": {"7d": 8.0},
 "Unique_sng_ecommerce_purchase": {"7d": null},
 "Unique_sng_login": {"7d": 20.0}
}
```

Desired output:

```
sng_ecommerce_purchase_revenue-7d: 18
unique_sng_content_view-7d: 25
Unique_login_send_otp-7d: 22
Unique_conversation_clicked-7d: 8
```

My query:

```
select json_extract(XYZ, '$.sng_ecommerce_purchase_revenue') as pr
from singular_reports_table
```

Output is

```
{"7d": 18}
```

Comment: Given the way you have stored the JSON, there isn't an easy way to do this in an SQL expression. I suggest you fetch the whole JSON document back to a client application and write code to present it however you want. The alternative is to change the way you are storing the JSON document to make it easier to query.

Comment: Isn't this the reason MongoDB exists?

Comment: Show output for `SELECT @@version;`.

Comment: Does properties names (i.e. `"sng_ecommerce_purchase_revenue"` and `"7d"`) are static and known, or they must be queried dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete solution to use:

Solution #1:

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT('sng_ecommerce_purchase_revenue',
          REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(JSON_EXTRACT(XYZ, '$.sng_ecommerce_purchase_revenue'),'{"','-'),'"',''),'}','')
     ) as PR
FROM singular_reports_table;
```

Solution #2:

```
SELECT 
      JSON_EXTRACT(XYZ, '$.sng_ecommerce_purchase_revenue."7d"') as PR
FROM singular_reports_table
```

[helped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41958183/mysql-5-7-error-3143-42000-invalid-json-path-expression-the-error-is-around)

Comment: Solution 2 works fine with SQL. But when I try to use this in app script (to auto update google sheets), they don't allow "7d", double quotes are not allowed. Any solution here?

Comment: "SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(XYZ, '$.sng_ecommerce_purchase_revenue.\"7d\"') as PR FROM singular_reports_table" pls try \"  ,,,